# Excel Snap to Grid Not Working Properly

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I have 'snap to grid' enabled in excel, it sometimes still does not place shapes exactly on the grid lines.

Is there a way to fix this?
Because it is messy, and will cause problems when moving multiple shapes in one go around.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Your shapes are the size of a cell.  Did you consider just using cells with borders?

Comment: you cant snap arrows to cells or easily move cells. Cell borders get cut off if you do ctrl+x and you still have to merge then unmerge them  when you want to edit them.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest(?) solution:

Hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> as you're about to (before you) release the mouse button while moving objects.

Note that the snapping at that point may be at ANY of the corners of the object, the difference may be very subtle; more so if the grid and object sizes are not exactly the same (i.e. differ only slightly).

Comment: I hope they are the same because that was the whole point of 'snap to grid'. Maybe I can lock just the width and height

Comment: All this does is fine move it somewhere, not snap it properly to the grid

Comment: I believe you have nothing more available than that. For a full fledged "snap" you need to use e.g. visio or similar.